# Import Typescript class into Jasmine tests (<type> is not a constructor error)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

If I have a class defined in a typescript file (`DateTimeConverter.ts`):

```
export class DateTimeConverter{
    constructor(){
    }
    //Other methods
}
```

And I then want to import this class to do some unit tests in Jasmine, so in my spec I import it:

```
var DateTimeConverter = require('../path/to/DateTimeConverter');
```

Why can I not use that class in my unit test:

```
var timeConverter = new DateTimeConverter();
```

When I run my tests, Jasmine gives an errorr:

> TypeError: DateTimeConverter is not a constructor

How can I pull this class in to my tests so I can test its functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured this out and thought I'd post the answer in case anyone else was stuck on this.
When you import the library, you (perhaps obviously) dont have direct access to the class, but a handle to it:

```
var DateTimeConverterLib = require('../path/to/DateTimeConverter');
```

You can then instantiate it:

```
var timeConverter = new DateTimeConverterLib.DateTimeConverter();
```

And then call any functions on it as you normally would:

```
var result = timeConverter.MyAwesomeTimeFunction();
```

Works like a charm and all my tests are now passing :)

Hope that helps someone

Comment: is it necessaty to use require for importing the module? Can it be done with `import { Class } from ".path/to/my/class.ts"`